# PHP mysql getting rows but result is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms application which uses a PHP webservice to acces a mysql database. So I wrote some code to return data from tables in JSON. It works fine for the most of the tables, but some tables are returning empty data.

```
if (isset($_GET['getall'])) {
    $table = $_GET['getall'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `p2byz_ticketmaster_" . $table . "`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($rows);
    } else {
        echo "De opgevraagde tabel is niet bekend: " . $table;
    }
}
```

When accessing let's say **table A** i'm echoing `mysqli_num_rows($result)` it returns '2' exactly the amount of rows in that table but `echo json_encode($rows);` stays empty.

Whem i'm accessing **table B** `mysqli_num_rows($result)` return 50 rows and `echo json_encode($rows);` returns all the data I need.

How is it possible that exactly the same code doesn't work on both tables?

Many thanks in advance!

Edit: added some screenshots from my data

**This one works:**
[image: This one works:]

**This one doesn't:**
[image: This one doesn't:]

Comment: using `var_dump($rows)` should give you some hints.

Comment: can you add some sample data from the tables? one that works and one that's not? also, did you tty mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Comment: @GuyL added some screenshots. First one works, second one stays empty.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @dustytrash it gives me a 500 error?

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! I'll take a look at that when i've got this working!

Comment: Maybe json_encode is producing an error, possibly on eventdescription.  Are you you outputting PHP errors to the screen?

Comment: I can assume that some info, maybe the html info, breaks the fetch. try the fetch_assoc

Comment: @Basvo if var_dump($rows) gives you a 500 error, try this instead: foreach ($rows as $object) {
    var_dump($object->debug());
}

Comment: @GuyL It deffinitely is that html info. Now selecting everything w/o that field and it works. But I still need to get that data too, to keep my function generic. fetch_assoc isn't working either.

Comment: @dmikester1 No currently I'm not putting any output to my screen. I'm very much a php noob, how do i do that?

Comment: nobody said to look at the logs and/or enable error reporting to show and display errors?  another being `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query. 500 error is a server error.

Comment: @Basvo try isolating the specific row with the problem, I would check that specific html inside... maybe a special key is damaging

Comment: Do this at the top of your PHP file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`